# Adjust characteristics in Table 1 using gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

I know that categories for a variable in table 1 usually should be mutually exclusive ==> sum of all categories should be 100%. However, for some diseases there are variations: like variable X have 3 categories: A, B, C, but any patient can have another feature: like A+p, B+P or C+p.
How can I shift this (p) as a category of variable X (like in my image:[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvHvg.jpg) moving "peri-anal disease in the picture into disease location)?

Thank you

Comment: make a new variable combining variable x and p into one variable then use that as the summary variable. I would need data and code to help further

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, we take the response variable and place the results under the "Grade" header.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.0'

tbl <-
  trial %>%
  select(grade, response, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(missing = "no") %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  # indent the response variable
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = label,
    row = variable == "response",
    text_format = "indent"
  ) %>%
  # undo the bolding for response variable
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = label,
    row = variable == "response",
    text_format = "bold",
    undo_text_format = TRUE
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-11-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Daniel!

I used the same code, but the variable is still in "bold", though It includes text_format = "indent"

Comment: without a reproducible example (aka minimal code that I can also run on my machine), there isn't much anyone can do to assist